# Default case is being executed before even entering switch-case

Tags: java, switch-statement

I run the program and it reaches while loop with input set on "" before the loop. When it enters the while loop it prints "Wrong input!" and then it asks to type in input = sc.nextLine(). Why? It hasn't even entered the switch-case statement.
Thank you in advance.

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size;
        size = sc.nextInt();
        String[] mem = new String[size];
        int[] mem_index = new int[size];
        String input = "";
        while(!input.equals("quit")) {
        input = sc.nextLine();

        switch(input) {
            case "Z": mem = memAlloc(mem, allocRequest);
                      memPrint(mem, mem_index);
                      allocRequest++;
                      break;
            case "O": System.out.print("Type memory data id: ");
                      delRequest = sc.nextInt();
                      mem = memDel(mem, mem_index, delRequest);
                      memPrint(mem, mem_index);
                      break;
            case "F": mem = memFrag(mem, mem_index);
                      memPrint(mem, mem_index);
                      break;
            case "quit":    break;
            default:  System.out.println("Wrong input!");
                      break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have code above this snippet that uses the scanner?  Are you using something like `nextInt` or `next` before this snippet?

Comment: Please add just a tiny bit more code so that this becomes a [mcve] that people can just run through javac to see if they can reproduce what you're seeing.

Comment: There is likely to be some unprocessed input in your scanner. I'd try printing out the value returned by sc.nextline() to see what is in there.

Comment: You should understand that `switch-case` is not executed like a block of `if-then-else` statements.  When execution enters a `switch-case`, execution is immediately dispatched to the matching case (or the default, if there is no match).   Your program will not check the cases in order until a match is found.

Comment: [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](//stackoverflow.com/q/13102045)

Comment: Found the explanation in topic from previous comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have something else in your `scanner`. Try adding this line:

```
sc.next();
```

before you go into the while loop or right in the beginning of your loop.